# Use custom TTF font in a PostScript file

Tags: truetype, postscript

I'm trying to write my own PostScript file manually and want to use a custom TTF font downloaded from the web but it's not using it - either uses some other font or doesn't display the text at all. I don't have problems with the fonts installed in the system.

The commands I used were different variations of:

`/FontName /TheFontName def
/TheFontName 20 selectfont
(XXXXXXXXXXX) show`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a TrueType font directly in PostScript, unlike PDF PostScript doesn't support TrueType.

In order to use a TrueType font you must first convert it into a type 42 font which PostScript does support.

[Adobe Technical Note 5012](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/font/pdfs/5012.Type42_Spec.pdf) documents the type 42 format

Comment: OK, I've just converted the font using this online service:
http://www.freefontconverter.com/ (got a file with the extension ".t42") but it's still not using it. How can I tell it to use this t42 file for my text? Maybe I'm using a wrong command?

Comment: OK, I've opened the T42 file and realized it's pure PostScript code so I copied it to my PS file in the beginning (before my code) and my code now can use the font!

Comment: @Val, have you discovered a "cleaner" or more dynamic way of doing this - without having to move the T42 font contents into your script?

Comment: No, I only had to do it that one time, luckily.

Answer (score 0):

You must convert ttf fonts to pfb and pfm format to use it in postscript. There are online tools available to convert ttf fonts to pfb and pfm format.